# Automatic image labelling for custom training YOLOv5

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, object-detection, bounding-box, yolov5

There are manual tools like Makesense.ai to create the labelled data for custom training YOLO, but is there any method for automatic labelling of multiple objects in an image so that the image labelling process would be faster?

Answer (score 1):

Makesense.ai has the very feature you are asking for. You can use a network trained on coco or provide your own yolov5 tensorflow js model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).